# Update tags lists - or updating has_many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, has-many, has-many-through

I often meet the problem of updating *has many* relationships.
For example, let's take the following three tables:

- posts
- tags
- posts_tags

When a user creates a new post, he can add tags to the post. Post is saved, and the selected tags are attached to it via _posts_tags_.

When user edits the post (and may or not edit the tag list too), and the form is submitted I have to update the post's tag list.

A solution can be the following: when updating a post, I delete all tags of that post from _posts_tags_, and insert the submitted ones.

Another solution is to get all tags of the post from db, compare the list with the submitted one and decide what we have to delete and what we have to insert.

Both solutions can be time consuming.
**What is a more clever solution for the problem?**

Comment: I'm a bit tired and drowsy so bear with me (might have read this wrong), but isnt that was cascading is for?

Comment: @Bono: No.  The question isn't how to cascade updates across related records in foreign tables, but rather how to detect which of a set of records have been modified in the application in order to reflect those modifications in the database.

Comment: Of the two solutions you posted, the first will often be preferable. A delete using an index will be quicker than the type of comparison required by the second. As for finding a more "clever" solution, should you consider applying the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) here?

Answer (score 0):

When a post is edited and the tags are not edited (optional), then simply save the post and do nothing. Why? Cause, in the posts, tags and posts_tags table you have an autoincrement column that is your primary key. This numeric column is then the foreign key in the respective tables i.e. the tables will look like the following:

posts: id_post(PK), post_title, post_content

Tags: id_tag(PK), tag_name

posts_tags: id_post_tag(PK), id_post(FK), id_tag(FK)

PK: Primary Key
FK: Foreign Key

Once you save the data in this format, you will find no need to update any dependent table as the textual data is no more used to maintain database schema and relationships. This also hastens transaction times as the database is not busy in any cascade job as Bono implied.

Then run a simple loop for all the tags in the post to check their existence against the id_post in the post_tags table and if not found then insert it. While doing this loop build a string that you will use below:

Next, run the following query:

```
delete from post_tags where id_post = {$id_post} and id_tag not in {$list_id_tags}
```

This operation minimizes database server overload by minimizing IO operations which are caused by rows being added and deleted. Your case of deleting all post_tags and then inserting all tags again would have generated large IO while this method minimizes that.